# Вывести меню Bootstrap из этих ссылок

Tags: javascript, массивы, bootstrap, меню

Дан многомерный массив

```
var links = [
  ['home', 'http://itstep.zp.ua'],
  ['contacts', 'https://itstep.zp.ua/contacts/'],
  ['news', 'https://itstep.zp.ua/news/'],
  ['success', 'http://success.itstep.org/'],
];
```

Comment: приведите пример нужного результата

Comment: просто надо сделать меню,

Comment: да все работает,скажите пожалуйста,а по коду попроще можно написать,через document.write?Я только начал учить JS

Comment: если с `document.write` , то можно сделать так https://pastebin.com/MUYndfYN

Comment: по ответу ниже все довольно таки просто - идет перебор массива с данными и добавление к параметру `nav` кода ссылки со значениями из массива. затем в строке `document.querySelector(".nav").innerHTML = nav;` идет поиск элемента `<nav class="nav"></nav>` и обновление его html.

Comment: Спасибо, большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var links = [
  ['home', 'http://itstep.zp.ua'],
  ['contacts', 'https://itstep.zp.ua/contacts/'],
  ['news', 'https://itstep.zp.ua/news/'],
  ['success', 'http://success.itstep.org/'],
];

let nav = '';
links.forEach(function(v){
 nav += '<a class="nav-link" href="' + v[1] + '">' + v[0] + '</a>';
});
document.querySelector(".nav").innerHTML = nav;
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="nav"></nav>
```